# How to add in carriage-return/line-feeds without starting a new row in a tabbed txt SQLite import

Tags: import, sqlite

I'm using a tab-delimited .txt file to save my data before importing it into a SQLite database with the SQLite Manager add-on for Firefox.

I've tried a couple of ways to add carriage-return/line-feeds within my columns but failed mostly, ending up with SQLite treating them as multiple rows.

I added a carriage-return/line-feed in SQLite Manager and then looked at the format which seems to be just simple returns but copy-and-pasting that into a text file for later importation doesn't work.

How can I add carriage-return/line-feed into columns within a text file that I can later import into SQLite?

Comment: @MaxVernon Is it called a line brake? Maybe I made up break return; I thought HTML's <br> was short for break return but I could have totally just made that up myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, fields containing newlines should be enclosed in double quotes:

```
123,test,456
234,"test with
multiple
lines", 567
```

When using quoted fields, any quote inside the field has to be escaped by another quote (or a `\`, unix style), and the field itself has to be quoted too:

```
123,"24"" monitor",456
234,"test with
multiple
lines", 567
345,no quotes needed,678
```